# Is it possible to run set the size of the Dock on Mojave/Sierra using write com.apple.dock tilesize?

Tags: bash, macos-sierra, macos-mojave

I'm writing a bash script for Mojave and Sierra for setting the dock size. I'm using sudo ./name_of_script on the shell and the bash  command that I'm implementing is: "defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 60; killall Dock". There may be a permissions conflict.

I have tested the "defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 60; killall Dock" commmand on a test script, but I noticed that it doesn't require sudo-ing it. Every time that I run; "sudo ./name_of_script" the dock size is not affected, but once I remove the sudo part, it does. The are some other functions in my script that requiere sudo permissions.

**bash code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 60; killall Dock

checkIfRoot 2> /dev/null

main
```

## there are some functions on main that require sudo permissions

**shell command:**

```
sudo ./script_name
```

**Expectation:** change the dock size on Mojave and Sierra by running a sudo ./script_name file command into a shell

Comment: If you run the script with `sudo`, `defaults write` is probably writing into the root user's account, not your account.

Comment: Remember, every user has their own Dock preferences.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this: username=${1-$(ls -l /dev/console | cut -d " " -f4)}

sudo -u $username defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 60; killall Dock

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 60; killall Dock
```

try this (assuming your username is `jdoe`):

```
sudo -u jdoe "defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 60; killall Dock"
```

Comment: Thanks, kaan. I ended up using this username=${1-$(ls -l /dev/console | cut -d " " -f4)}

sudo -u $username defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 60; killall Dock